# What is the opening song in the Nickelodeon TV movie "Best Player"?

Tags: soundtrack, best-player

Long time back I watched the Nickelodeon tv movie [Best Player](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535615/). A song comes in the starting and it goes like... always the lucky one.

It's been a month and I can't find the full version of this song to listen(online). Please help, I really love this song.

Comment: Is it not one of the songs listed on the IMDB Soundtrack section?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535615/soundtrack?ref_=tt_trv_snd

Comment: Maybe it's the same song, but when I google it, nothing concrete comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a full version too, but here's the scene from the movie

I think it could be "The Lucky One" by "James Renald" from ["Sky"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_%28Canadian_band%29)

Comment: The video is private :(

Comment: @Rippy  Ah my bad. You can view it now. Also [here](http://www.primewire.ag/external.php?title=Best+Player&url=aHR0cDovL3ZpZHppLnR2L3hrNGJteTM3Yzlhai5odG1s&domain=dmlkemkudHY=&loggedin=0) where i found the movie, not a good quality though

Comment: @Rippy Happy to help